# How to use bluetooth module?

Tags: bluetooth, serial-port

I recently purchased a Bluetooth module from China.  Now that I have it I have no idea how to use it.  I cannot even get my computer to find it.  I have tried connecting the "mode pin" to ground and to Vcc, but that does not make it discoverable.

How I can get my computer connected to this?  And once I do, how can I actually use it like a serial port?

Thank you.

Here is a photo of the module.
[image: Here is the module]

Comment: Do you have also a datasheet of the module?

Comment: Unfortunately I do not.  That is the downside to buying from these Chinese people that make this stuff in their apartment.  I have a datasheet for the module itself (the green part) but not for the host, and that isn't actually too helpful..

Comment: post what you have, maybe we can help you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I posted this question on the Electrical Engineering site as well, and I got a good answer from them folks.

You can [check it out here.](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/35630/how-to-use-arduino-bluetooth-module)

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this links, I guess that they match your board:

http://iteadstudio.com/produce/serial-port-bluetooth-module-slave-connect-to-pc/

http://www.elechouse.com/elechouse/index.php?main_page=product_info&cPath=90_91&products_id=647

http://www.robotshop.com/content/PDF/SeeedStudio-Bluetooth-Module-Manual-v1.2.pdf

http://www.robotshop.com/seeedstudio-serial-bluetooth-module.html

This is a Bluetooth 2.0 module, based on CSR BlueCore 4 chip. The blue board in my opinion is just adapter so you can easly integrate it in other prototypes. You can connect it through UART to an embedded board like Arduino, LaunchPad, or to a PC (you would need a supplementary adapter).